# Issue with BST - no comma inserted between Publisher and Address

Tags: bibtex, errors, bst

I am personalizing the IEEEtran.bst file to adapt it for another journal, which already has bibliography rules since many years (but not a latex class). As I prepared the latex class for typesetting the manuscripts, I'm also trying to finalize the BST file.

However I have a specific issue I am unable to solve.

Specifically, the IEEEtran.bst file has a piece of code, starting at line 1150, that define a function like `FUNCTION {format.address.org.or.pub.date}`.
Here all the styles for typesetting the address, the organization and the publisher, and the publication dates are applied, as well as their order.

*I am editing my question from now on, to add a MWE.*

I have changed the function, as the bibliography style I have to map has different rules for ordering of items and punctuation.
However, now I am stuck with an issue.

Specifically, my need was to change the way "Publisher" and "Address" are typesetter to output. That is, from **Address: Publisher** output string to **Publisher, Address**

After lot of testing, I have been able to introduce check to suppress extra commas if I don't specify the Organization and/or the publisher, like in the original IEEEtran.

however, my modified style will produce the output string **PublisherAddress**, i.e. with the two strings attached, which is clearly wrong and awful to see.

Below is the portion of the code that I significantly modified (just for that specific function). The original IEEEtran.bst can be easily found on CTAN for comparison:

```
FUNCTION {format.address.org.or.pub.date}
{ 't :=
  ""
  year empty$
    { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$ }
    { skip$ }
  if$
  address empty$ t empty$ and
  year empty$ and month empty$ and
    { skip$ }
    { this.to.prev.status
      this.status.std
      cap.status.std
      t empty$
        { skip$ }
        { punct.comma 'prev.status.punct :=
          t *
        }
      if$
      address "address" bibinfo.check *
      year empty$ month empty$ and
        { skip$ }
        { 
          month empty$
            { year empty$
                { skip$ }
                { ", " * year "year" bibinfo.check * }
              if$
            }
            { ", " * month "month" bibinfo.check *
              year empty$
                 { skip$ }
                 { ", " * year "year" bibinfo.check * }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

As a MWE, you can test it with the following tiny .tex file, along with the BST file (you can download it from here
[testbst.bst](https://github.com/trama/Acta-Imeko-Latex-Class/blob/04ec1efd50ca3563e73fecf120d90fa950fcc583/mwe%20for%20bst/testbst.bst) and a [testbib.bib](https://github.com/trama/Acta-Imeko-Latex-Class/blob/04ec1efd50ca3563e73fecf120d90fa950fcc583/mwe%20for%20bst/testbib.bib) file)

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\title{Template}
\author{John Doe}
\begin{document}
\cite{*}
\bibliographystyle{testbst}
\bibliography{testbib}
\end{document}
```

Just to provide a very quick example, let's suppose to have two entries in the bib file:

```
@InCollection{Grattan1994,
  author    = {K. T. V. Grattan},
  title     = {Measurement: system of scales and units},
  booktitle = {Concise Encyclopedia of Measurement and Instrumentation},
  publisher = {Pergamon Press},
  year      = {1994},
  editor    = {L. Finkelstein and K. T. V. Grattan},
  pages     = {209 - 214},
  address   = {Oxford},
  isbn      = {0-08-036212-5},
}

@InProceedings{Lighthill1950,
  author    = {M. J. Lighthill},
  title     = {Contribution to the theory of heat transfer through a laminar boundary layer},
  booktitle = {Proc. of Royal Society},
  year      = {1950},
  volume    = {A202},
  number          = {3},
  pages     = {359-377},
  address   = {London},
  publisher       = {Publisher},
}
```

These will be rendered as in the attached image
[image: wrong output]
where you can see the Publisher/Address issue quite evidently.

I have tried all my best to but a "comma" + "space" between them, but without any luck.
Thanks to these efforts, I have been able to solve the issue with the extra commas, but now I found this other issue...Perhaps it is the last one ;)

I hope my explanation are sufficient to let someone of you, surely much more expert than me, to help me finding the issue.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Could you also add a small compilable document that people can use to test with. You can also include the `.bib` file using `filecontents`.  I've removed your "thanks" statement which isn't used on the site.

Comment: You presumably want if empty checks adding to the the functions you have not shown that typeset the publisher and organisation fields

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle. Actually, it is exactly that... however I am not able to obtain the desired result. Obviously it is my fault, but I am here to kindly ask for an help, since I am not able to find a solution by myself. 
As a further comment, please notice that the "original" lines of code, corresponding to the function FUNCTION {format.address.org.or.pub.date}, that is, those in the original IEEEtran.bst that I then modified as shown above, this issue does not appear, i.e. the original IEEEtran.bst is able to suppress commas for missing fields. 

In the next hours I will push a MWE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have autonomously solved the issue.

For the sake of the community, I post here the solution.
The point was that, with respect to the IEEEtran.bst, I inverted the code that write the Publisher and the Address.

Specifically, the IEEEtran.bst style prints the string **Address: Publisher** in the .bbl file, and if we focus only on the interested lines in the function `FUNCTION {format.address.org.or.pub.date}` they are like this:

```
  address empty$ t empty$ and
  year empty$ and month empty$ and
    { skip$ }
    { this.to.prev.status
      this.status.std
      cap.status.std
      address "address" bibinfo.check *
      t empty$
        { skip$ }
        { punct.period 'prev.status.punct :=
          space.large 'prev.status.space :=
          address empty$
            { skip$ }
            { ": " * }
          if$
          t *
        }
      if$
```

After a bit of testing, I was able to invert and get the output string ** PublisherAddress**, substituting the above lines with these ones:

```
  address empty$ t empty$ and
  year empty$ and month empty$ and
    { skip$ }
    { this.to.prev.status
      this.status.std
      cap.status.std
      t empty$
        { skip$ }
        { punct.comma 'prev.status.punct :=
          t *
        }
      if$
      address "address" bibinfo.check *
```

My original question was "how to introduce a "comma + space" between the Publisher and the Address?

The point, that I was missing before, is the use of the concatenation in BST language, which is obtained with the `*` operator and using RPN.

Therefore, considering that `t` is the variable that hosts the "Publisher" value on the stack, it was sufficient to simply concatenate the desired string (in my case ", ") to the value that is obtained from the stack. In practice:

```
  address empty$ t empty$ and
  year empty$ and month empty$ and
    { skip$ }
    { this.to.prev.status
      this.status.std
      cap.status.std
      t empty$
        { skip$ }
        { punct.comma 'prev.status.punct :=
          %t * % here we concatenate t with the previous strings
          t * ", " * % now we take the result of the concatenation and concatenate with ", "
        }
      if$
      address "address" bibinfo.check *
```

I how that the answer to my post may help someone else, struggling with the BST language.

Cheers

Federico